# FIDO2 security keys - what attack vectors/weaknesses exist for "bad" keys

Tags: fido2

What attack vectors exist for "bad" FIDO USB keys? What would the weaknesses of a "bad" key be?  How could they be compromised?

1. This came to mind as I was looking at "make your own key" projects - what weaknesses would they have compared to a professionally designed commercial key?  Example projects:
   https://github.com/canokeys/canokey-nrf52
   https://github.com/mphi-rc/pi-zero-security-key
   https://github.com/conorpp/u2f-zero
   https://makerdiary.com/blogs/news/getting-started-with-google-opensk
   and this one, that bills itself as "the most unsafe key that supports FIDO2":
   https://github.com/sb-child/unsafe-key-source
2. There are presumably weak commercial options - what weaknesses would they have versus a good implementation?

Here are some guesses:

1. The private key stored on the key could be poorly protected - it would be possible to extract the private key through physical attack or malicious code
2. Poor generation of keys - make it possible to guess the private key

Anything else?

Comment: 1) The question is very broad. Please put every question into a separate post. 2) Product recommendations are off-topic on Security SE.

Comment: The key being evil itself: https://www.blackhillsinfosec.com/how-to-weaponize-the-yubikey/

Comment: @mentallurg - thanks, I wasn't clear with where I was going with the homemade keys.  I'm not looking for a recommendation on a build-your-own project - I have a commercial key.  I was just aware of the need to protect the storage of the private keys, saw one project bill itself as unsafe, and wondered what vulnerabilities existed from a "bad" key.